# Installing p7zip on CentOS 5

Tags: centos5, installation, compression

I need some help here..., I'm working on a windows PC, SSHed into my server.  I want to install p7zip (linux command line version of 7zip):  http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/9.20.1/

Which package do I grab there?  I have no need to make this myself on my server, I'd be happy to just get it on there and get it running...  Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p7zip` is available in `epel` repo:

```
Name       : p7zip
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 9.20.1
Release    : 2.el5
Size       : 745 k
Repo       : epel
Summary    : Very high compression ratio file archiver
URL        : http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/
License    : LGPLv2 and (LGPLv2+ or CPL)
Description: p7zip is a port of 7za.exe for Unix. 7-Zip is a file archiver with a very high
           : compression ratio. The original version can be found at http://www.7-zip.org/.
```

Install [epel](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) repo:

```
# rpm -ivh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

and use `yum` to install `p7zip`:

```
# yum -y install p7zip
```

Comment: Is this better than the RPM method that MDPC wrote below for some reason?

Comment: It is more convenient because you don't have to find, download and install manually.

Comment: Gotcha.  But in this case, since It's already found and moved to the server - no difference...right (just one line at the command prompt either way)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd pickup the package from somewhere like:

```
 http://pkgs.repoforge.org/p7zip/p7zip-9.20.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

And then

```
 rpm --install p7zip-9.20.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

it (as root of course).  I have choosen the 64-bit version but the 32-bit version is there also.

PS:  Don't be afraid to use google to find the package you are looking for.

Comment: so literally, download it on windows, send over the file to any directory on the server, and after I do the rpm command on it, it's installed?  Why did I think this was way more complicated?

Comment: sorry, also:  if something goes wrong, how can I go back?

Comment: rpm is a fairly robust program and it should not fail and if there is some problem all still should be ok.